# Как добавить значения из массива в уже существующие в dom теги?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть массив `[1, 2 , 3]` и есть в DOM три тега `<h1>`. Как так циклом пройтись по массиву, чтоб прописать каждому `<h1>`  значения . Нужно чтоб получилось

```
<h1>1 </h1>,
<h1>2 </h1>,
<h1>3 </h1>
```

Comment: $('h1') содержит массив всех <h1> на странице, думаю намек ясен?

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Получить коллекцию `<h1>` или задать содержимое для тега?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример на чистом `js` с проверкой против выхода за пределы массивов:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var ah1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
var len = Math.min(arr.length, ah1.length); 

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ah1[i].textContent = arr[i];
}
```

```html
<h1>0</h1>
<h1>0</h1>
<h1>0</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью метода `document.getElementsByTagName`, вот так:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

var h1s = document.getElementsByTagName("H1");

for(var i = 0; i < h1s.length; i++) {
  h1s[i].innerHTML = arr[i] + " ";
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
```

Или, если хочется использовать jQuery:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];

$("h1").each(function(i) {
  $(this).html(arr[i] + " ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
```